# Global theme customization multisite

Tags: customization, multisite

I want to be able to customize my theme from any of my sites (mainsite or any subsite) and have that change impact on the entire network.

Right now when I customize, i.e., my main site it doesn't replicate the changes to the rest of subsites.

I know this data is stored under **theme_mods_themename**, but I need to "copy and paste" this new values (New values generated when I use the customizer) on every site.

Is there a way to "unify" this setting?

Thank you in advance.

***UPDATE (DECEMBER 21 2021):***

I've found another thing that was making me lose my mind. At least in my case, theme colors are not stored with the rest of the theme settings in `theme_mods_kadence-child`, they are stored under `kadence_global_palette` in the `wp-options` database table.

Still haven't found a way to "Sync" all customizer settings tho. I've been reading about what Pat J said in the first comment, but couldn't crack it yet.

***UPDATE (DECEMBER 23 2021)*** 
I finaly solved it! Answer bellow !

Comment: If I was developing this, I'd start by looking at using the [`update_option_theme_mods_{$theme}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option_option/) action hook to update a network option when your theme mods are updated, and then pulling that network option's data back out with the [`theme_mod_{$name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_mod_name/) filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it! If you are going to use this code make sure to change the options names to the ones that your theme uses (change "theme_mods_kadence-child" and "kadence_global_palette").

I used [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) to get the recently saved data, then I looped through all sites and used [update_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) to set the new data on all subsites. Finally I used the [customize_save_after](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save_after/) action so this function activates just after the new customizer data is saved.

```
add_action( "customize_save_after", "update_customizer_networkwide");
function update_customizer_networkwide () {
    // Get current theme mods
    $theme_mods_kadence = get_option("theme_mods_kadence-child");
    $global_palette = get_option("kadence_global_palette");


    // loop through all sites and set new theme mods
    $sites = get_sites();
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );

        update_option("theme_mods_kadence-child", $theme_mods_kadence);
        update_option("kadence_global_palette", $global_palette);
        
        restore_current_blog();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps some of you!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Be aware, though, that on a large Multisite installation, `switch_to_blog()` can start to slow things down. I'd still recommend saving the data in a network option, which can be accessed from any site (see [`update_site_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_site_option/) and its relations).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into it.
It should work with `update_site_option()` and `get_site_option()`.